# How to sort number of lines per date in a file?

Tags: sort

I have a file like this :

```
$ more messages
Jan  2 random text
Jan  2 random text
Jan  3 random text
Jan  2 random text
Jan  3 random text
Jan  3 random text
Jan  3 random text
```

And I want to have this, using `sort` :

```
Jan  2 : 3
Jan  3 : 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `cut` to split the characters you're interested in, then `sort` and `uniq -c` to count how many times the different dates appear:

```
$ < input cut -c1-6 |sort |uniq -c
  3 Jan  2
  4 Jan  3
```

Or use `awk` if you're particular about the output format:

```
$ awk '{a[substr($0, 1, 6)] += 1} END { for (x in a) printf "%s : %d\n", x, a[x] }' < x | sort
Jan  2 : 3
Jan  3 : 4
```

The first block uses an associative array to count how many times each date appears, end the END block just prints out the dates and their counts. `sort` the output afterwards since there's no guarantee on the order the keys come out of the array.

Comment: Using awk associative arrays to count appearances of lines or strings is rather common, there's a number of answers using that here, but I'm not sure if I could find an exact duplicate to this, so here it is again.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks a lot. I understand where I was wrong.

Comment: Beware the sorting won't be chronological. With GNU sort you can sort with `-k1,1M -k2n`. Using `LC_ALL=C` would ensure that `Jan␣␣3` sorts before `Jan␣20`.